# Mirror image video using xdg-open

Tags: arch-linux, camera, xdg-open

I am using a web cam in Zoom, which opens xdg-open to provide the video feed.

Unfortunately the feed is mirror image, so if I have text in the image then it is reversed and unreadable.

How can I modify the xdg-open settings to have a right facing image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xdg-open has nothing to do with the presentation, and has no user options. It is just a wrapper that launches another application from the command line.

What application does the image come up in (it should have an about or help menu)? That's what needs configuration. xdg-open just uses a file association to determine the app to run.

A search on 'webcam reversed image in zoom' got me a one-minute YouTube.

Zoom->Video Settings->Mirror My Video (click).

Comment: Zoom is the application.